# Writing a Prolog rule for messages before a given date

Tags: prolog

How do I write a Prolog rule that given two people, tests if there has been a message sent in either direction between them before a given date?

So far I have:

```
?- MBefore(x,y) :- message(x,y,d1), message(y,x,d1), d1@<Date.
```

Comment: Variables in Prolog must start with an upper case letter. Predicates should start with a lower case letter. You should go through an introductory Prolog tutorial before attempting this.

Comment: so how would i go about this rule?

Comment: What does a "date" look like?

Answer (score 1):

`mbefore(X,Y,D) :- message(X,Y,D1), D > D1 ; message(Y,X,D1), D > D1.`

Here `','` means *"and"*, `';'` means *"or"*. Both alternatives of the *"or"* combination are tried, independently. First the system attempts to prove the first alternative (to the left of `;`), then the search backtracks, any logical variables are restored to their previous states, and the second alternative (to the right of ';') is tried. That's why we can use the same logvar `D1` in both alternatives of the *"or"*-combination.

Also, `':-'` means *"holds, if the following can be proven"*.

If any of the above is new for you, you really should study the basics of the language through some tutorials or textbooks.  "The Art of Prolog" is an excellent introductory book.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped a lot!  And yes, Prolog is new to me so I will consider that book!

Comment: Erm, what do you mean by "mbefore"?

Comment: same thing that the OP meant by `MBefore`. -- Another possible answer to this: I mean `message(X,Y,D1), D > D1 ; message(Y,X,D1), D > D1`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Is D, the given date, or is that D1. if not what do they both mean?

Comment: the OP asks for a predicate expressing "there was a message between X and Y, before the date D". This is true, if there was an outgoing message from X to Y on date D1, and D1 < D; or if there was an outgoing message from Y to X on date D1 (same name, another value), and this D1 < D. Otherwise there was no message between X and Y prior to the date D.

Comment: @user3065332 - Are you also doing coursework on Prolog as well by any chance?

Comment: The rule                                                  mbefore(X,Y,D) :- message(X,Y,D1), D > D1 ; message(Y,X,D1), D > D1." is misleading. only the rule just before the close of the first bracket is run. D>D1 is not even considered by prolog.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 you are mistaken. rules are not run, they are tried. Also, I don't know what you mean by "bracket".

Comment: ok the let me rephrase. The rule, message(Y,X,D1), is all that is tried. Anything else after that has no effect on the outcome of that rule. You can write a few facts to test it out if you want.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 `mbefore(X,Y,D):- ...` is a rule. `message(X,Y,D1)`, as well as `message(Y,X,D1)`, are goals in it that are supposed to match (or not match) facts in the current Prolog database.