# Prolog: Simple date range selection rule

Tags: prolog

I am a bit stuck on this question - Write a rule where given two people `A` and `B` and a date `D` returns the list of all dates of when `A` and `B` have exchanged messages until date `D`.

I have this so far but I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
mexchanged(A,B,D) :- message(A,B,D1), D > D1.
```

And secondly, I am completely stuck on this - Write a rule that counts the number of messages sent for each person in a database of facts.

How do I write these rules?

edit: sorry I forgot to post these before;, these are few of the facts.

```
message(ben, tom, '20-03-2011').
message(kim, james, '17-11-2011').
message(ben, kim, '06-12-2011').
message(harry, jacky, '29-09-2011').
message(barry, chin, '06-01-2011').
```

Comment: You seem like you are on track, where is `G` coming from however? What facts are currently defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a Prolog rule for messages before a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763928/writing-a-prolog-rule-for-messages-before-a-given-date)

Comment: BTW, the G was suppose to be D. I have changed it now.

Comment: do you know about [`findall`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3)?

Comment: Please do not erase the question once it has been answered as this page will no longer have value to anyone if there is no question.

Comment: sorry jasper, the question wasn't answered accordingly to the question , so I thought it won't be of use to anyone.

Comment: when you edit, please do not erase your question, but add to it.  Please explain what do you mean by "returns the list of all dates...". Show us your desired query, at least. What do you want to type at the Prolog prompt? How do you want it to respond? Please respond in the comments. Do not continue erasing your question's text; this is not how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not that far off, except I have no idea what `G` is representing here:

```
message(hunter, user3147584, '12-30-2013').
message(hunter, mom,         '12-29-2013').
message(hunter, user3147584, '12-28-2013').

% predicate to test for exchanged messages
mexchanged(A,B,D) :- message(A,B,D1), D @> D1 ; 
                     message(B,A,D1), D @> D1 .

% example
mexchanged(hunter, user3147584, '12-29-2013').
% output = true
```

Comment: The one catch here is that the date format won't compare chronologically with `@>` since it's in `MM-DD-YYYY` format. It would need to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to compare properly. So either the OP would need to change the date format, or create a simple predicate to compare the date, such as `date-earlier(M1-D1-Y1, M2-D2-Y2) :- Y1-M1-D1 @< Y2-M2-D2.`.